# How can I prove that when $A$ is a symmetric matrix, $χA(A) = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a square, symmetric matrix of size $n$. The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is given by $\chi A(x)$. How do I go about proving $\chi A(A) = 0$ using the fact that $A$ is symmetric?

Also, how do I write a simple proof (proving the same thing above) when $A$ is not symmetric and just any square matrix of size $n$?

And, what would the degree of $\chi A(A)$ be?

Comment: This is Cayley-Hamilton (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) there is also a proof there. I would suggest looking in any basic linear algebra book for further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A symmetric matrix is always diagonalizable. So you can write $A=M^{-1}DM$ for $D$ a diagonal matrix. Now, notice that $A^k=M^{-1}D^kM$ for all $k\ge0$. Then, if you consider the characteristic polynomial $\chi_A(A)$, you have that $\chi_A(A)=M^{-1}\chi_A(D)M$. But $D$ is diagonal, so if for example

$$ D=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} \lambda_1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \ddots & 0\\
0&0&\lambda_n\end{array}\right)$$

then you have

$$ \chi_A(D) = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} \chi_A(\lambda_1) & 0 & 0\\
0 & \ddots & 0\\
0&0&\chi_A(\lambda_n)\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \ddots & 0\\
0&0&0\end{array}\right)=0$$

where $\chi_A(\lambda_k)=0$ because the $\lambda_k$'s are the eigenvalues of $D$ (that coincide with the eigenvalues of $A$). So $\chi_A(D)=0$ and $\chi_A(A)=0$, as wanted. If $A$ isn't symmetric, the result is still true and you have to use the Jordan normal form of $A$ instead of $D$.